# Rolling with slipping along an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

[image: The question]

Here my doubt is about the second question. For the second question I went about using work energy theorem. My thought was that since gravitational and frictional force both will do the same amount of work on all bodies ( as the distance moved by the bodies are same and since friction is limiting) so the final kinetic energy will be same for all bodies.

But when I went about seeing the solution of  the second question they argued that since acceleration will be same for all bodies so their **translational kinetic energy** will be same. And since angular acceleration will be most for the body with least moment of inertia as torques is same for all(by the friction). So hollow sphere has least **Total** kinetic energy  as it's **rotational kinetic energy**  energy will be least.

Could someone point out the fault in my solution because I don't find anything wrong in the second solution